# Automatically pull from remote using GitHub Actions

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, command-line-interface, github-actions

I have a private repository on GitHub and my goal is that whenever there is a new commit, the repository us updated on the VPS.

[image: What I am currently doing is using an SSH action to log on to the server, locate the repository, and pull from the origin]

The issue with this is that the repository is private and requires authentication. I tried settings my username and password in the global git config but even after doing that it still requires authentication.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured out the solution on my own. The issue with the various things I was doing was as follows. I was trying to do something along the lines of `git pull https://${{ secrets.TOKEN }}@github.com/repo`

The solution was putting the entire command `git pull https://token@github.com/repo` as a secret and then running the script: `${{ secrets.SCRIPT }}` via SSH.

My action at the end of this:

```
name: Remote SSH
on: [push]
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: executing remote ssh commands using password
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.IP }}
        username: ${{ secrets.USER }}
        password: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
        port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
        script: |
          cd Repository
          ${{ secrets.SCRIPT}}
          pm2 restart 0
```

Comment: Interesting hack, thanks! Another thing that could be done is to `scp` the built files from the github action container to the VPS.

Answer (score 2):

According to the doc you can use env like this

```
  - name: pass environment
    uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
    env:
      FOO: "BAR"
      BAR: "FOO"
      SHA: ${{ github.sha }}
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
      username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
      key: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
      port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
      envs: FOO,BAR
      script: |
        echo "I am $FOO"
        echo "I am $BAR"
        echo "sha: $SHA"
```

Comment: Can you put the link to the doc?

Comment: https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action#pass-environment-variable-to-shell-script

Answer (score 2):

Oh great your own solution fixed my problem!

I only changed the command putting the specific branch I want because it was not updating well the branch, so my own solution is:

```
git pull https://${{secrets.PAT}}@github.com/repo.git branch_name
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't understand which token to use, in one example he used secrets.PAT

PAT for Personnal Access Token

It seems logical but I took time to understand. I tried with Oauth token but it's not working since the scopes are not enough with this king of token to make a git pull on a private repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you have troubles with the pull script, maybe adding a couple lines to reset and clean can help. Make sure the remote directory is at the **correct branch**.

```
name: Remote SSH
on: [push]
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: executing remote ssh commands using password
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.IP }}
        username: ${{ secrets.USER }}
        password: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
        port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
        script: |
          cd Repository
          git fetch origin
          git clean -df
          ${{ secrets.SCRIPT}}
          pm2 restart 0
```

This helped me make a clean pull on every action.