# GitHub Actions: How to automatically pull and merge on a remote server

Tags: git, github, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I have a repo in GitHub with 2 branches (`dev` & `master`) and an app on a local apache server hosted in my house (the server has a public ip). Currently, whenever I make changes to `dev`, I push the code, make a pull request, merge the change to `master` and do `git pull` on the apache server after ssh into it.

What I want to do is to set up an automatic workflow using GitHub Actions so that the server automatically does `git pull` to pull the change from github whenever there is a change. I set up a workflow in yml file and self-hosted runner in the local apache server.

However, I haven't figured it out how to structure yml file. I have copied my yml file below. This yml file returns 'Already up to date' even though there is a change in the remote branch.

I found a couple of articles like this ([Automatically pull from remote using GitHub Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61447350/automatically-pull-from-remote-using-github-actions)) in stackoverflow and it uses ssh and and also doesn't use self-hosted runner. I am confused whether i should use self-hosted or not. My thinking was since it is a local server, I have to make my server listen to the change and pull the code from github.

Can somebody help me out on this? I highly appreciate the help.

```
name: Test

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Pull the change from server
        env:
          USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
        run: | 
          git pull origin master --rebase
          echo $USERNAME
          echo $TOKEN
```

Comment: The `git pull ...` command is executed in the runner environment and working directory and not under a specific user on this self-hosted machine. There are no changes since the branch was just checked out in the previous step by `actions/checkout@v2`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So, I think that `git pull` was executed too early. Does delaying commands fix this issue? Or should the file ssh into the server to run commands?

Comment: Delaying won't fix the issue as the working directory stays the same. When you arrive at the second step, you already have the latest state of the checked-out branch. The workflow then needs to execute commands to actually deploy the changes.

Comment: Gotcha. So, I guess the solution here is to run the actual commands on the server. I need to let yml file talk to the server via ssh and execute the commands in it. Is that right or is there any other way?